# Get the currently active line of a word document

Tags: c#, ms-word

My goal is to insert some text into a word document at the active line where the keyboard-cursor is located. I was able to insert it after a specific bookmark but i want to give the user the possibilty to insert it wherever he wants.

At the moment i'm using this code:

```
    Word.Application oWordApp;
    Word.Document oWordDoc;

    oWordApp = (Word.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
    oWordDoc = oWordApp.ActiveDocument;

    object docAction = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdGoToItem.wdGoToBookmark;
    object docTarget = "TextBegin";
    object n = Type.Missing;

    oWordApp.Selection.GoTo(ref docAction, ref n, ref n, ref docTarget);
    oWordApp.Selection.InsertAfter("Test");
```

Now I'm searching for a method to get the current selected line, so I can use:

```
object docAction = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdGoToItem.wdGoToLine
```

All I found was about getting the range between two objects or go to a concrete row/line.

Can anyone tell me what I have to do or whereupon I have to search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you already have it.  oWordApp.Selection is the currently selected range or insertion point.

Comment: Thank you very much! This changes did it:  

    `object docAction = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdGoToItem.wdGoToLine;  
 object docTarget = oWordApp.Selection;`